# Restrict scopes to certain users

Tags: doorkeeper

Say I have 2 scopes: read, write. What would be the cleanest way for me to only allow specific users (for example, current_user.admin?) to authorize on the write scope?

Answer (score 0):

I did this by extending the AuthorizationsController, and adding a before_action for new/create.